# Share link via twitter not work

Tags: html, twitter

This is my implementation of tweet button

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=generated_url" 
   class="twitter-share-button" 
   data-text="Hi, you can see my presentation on this link">Tweet
</a>
```

There is something like list of presentations and every one has tweet button and itself generated url to share.

It working well, post tweet like I want - text and url. But, when I tweet via this button, link on twitter is **unclickable**. What is wrong?

**EDIT:**

unclickable - showed as plain text, example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 'unclickable'. Can you maybe giva a link with one of those tweets so we can see it by ourselfs.

Comment: Unclickable I mean, when you see my tweet, URL/link will be as **plain text**. Here is actual screenshot http://prntscr.com/4eya60. (I will also add it to the question).

Comment: Have you tried it with anything else then localhost?

Comment: I cannot push 'uncomplete' issue on live website.

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, but the links with "localhost" are not clickable.
I had the same problem until I tested with a "live/public" link.

Your generated_url should not contain localhost, but http ://www . yoursite . com / data

Answer (score 0):

I think [this page on the twitter dev docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213713/twitter-share-link-with-parameters) can help a lot. For what i found there, it would be something like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-lang="en" 
data-url="http://this.url.com/foo/bar">Tweet</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: I also tried sent URL as `data-` attribute, but same problem.